# SVN file update does not appear to be updating

Tags: svn

Ok, I did a

> svn update

on my repo, but one particular file does not appear to have updated. I think the issue is in part due to someone else working on the same file as well. Like I was working on the file, they apparently did some heavy tweaking. They committed theirs and I said to myself no worries my changes are minor. So I figured I'd update to have the newest stuff, and let my changes get overwritten cause I could just redo my stuff real quick. Unfortunately that wasn't the case.

When I did the update, the SVN shows the file as having updated, but when I open the file, theres no change. So I'm guess SVN is smart enough to not let me overwrite my files like I was hoping to do. With that I figure theres gotta be a way to reset the file, or force it to take on the changes. I just don't know SVN well enough to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *delete* your file first, then run `svn update`, then the file will be replaced by the latest from the repository. Your changes cannot be involved, since you deleted them first. However...

Normally, Subversion will *merge* the changes from the repository into your working file. In the event of a successful merge with no conflicts, both your changes *and* the other changes will be present in the file in your working directory after an `svn update`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have some major misunderstanding of how SVN works.  Take a look in the SVN book and learn about what will happen if 2 people is modifying same file concurrently.

I will point out the mistakes in your question first, before giving the answer:

1. You are not performing `svn update` on the repo, you are performing on your *working copy*
2. If you changed file A in your local working copy, and someone else changed A too, and committed.  When you update your working copy, SVN will try to merge your change, and changes happened in the repo (starting from your previous update/checkout).  The result will seems like you are modifying the file base on the latest file A.  It will **NOT** overwrite your local change.
3. I don't believe there is "no change" after your update.  I bet you still see your changes, therefore you think there is no change, am I right?

After talking about the mistakes, here is the answer:
If you want to give up what you have changed for certain file, and use the file on repository instead, you should use `svn revert`.

Either `svn revert` the file before or after update should both work.